# multiple operation on list data using stream api

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-8, java-stream

I have a requirement to calculate the basket price. I am getting list of items as an input, and first calculating the price of each item using map. After that I have to calculate the basket total and return ShoppingBasketOutput. I have attached my code below, but I don't like the idea of passing ShoppingBasketOutput into calculateBasketPrice as a param.

Do you a better suggestion to implement this requirement?

```
public ShoppingBasketOutput getBasketTotalPrice(List<ShoppingItemDTO> itemsDTO) {
    ShoppingBasketOutput shoppingBasketOutput = new ShoppingBasketOutput();

    itemsDTO.stream()
            .map(this::calculateItemPrice)
            .forEach((item) -> calculateBasketPrice(shoppingBasketOutput, item));
    return shoppingBasketOutput;
}

private ShoppingBasketOutput calculateBasketPrice(ShoppingBasketOutput shoppingBasketOutput, ShoppingItemDTO item) {
    shoppingBasketOutput.setSubTotal(shoppingBasketOutput.getSubTotal() + item.getItemSubTotal());
    shoppingBasketOutput.setTotalDiscount(shoppingBasketOutput.getTotalDiscount() + item.getTotalItemDiscount());
    return shoppingBasketOutput;
}

private ShoppingItemDTO calculateItemPrice(ShoppingItemDTO shoppingItemDTO) {
    Optional<ItemEnum> itemEnum = ItemEnum.getItem(shoppingItemDTO.getName());
    if (itemEnum.isPresent()) {
        ItemEnum item = itemEnum.get();
        shoppingItemDTO.setTotalItemDiscount(getItemTotalDiscount(item, shoppingItemDTO.getQuantity()));
        shoppingItemDTO.setItemSubTotal(item.getPrice() * shoppingItemDTO.getQuantity());
    } else {
        throw new ProductNotFoundException();
    }
    return shoppingItemDTO;
}
```

Comment: Why does `calculateItemPrice` return an item instead of a price?

Comment: This is really unclear. I don't see how the code can even compile and produce a correct result here. So you need to explain better `calculateItemPrice` does and return, what `ShoppingBasketOutput` is and what `ShoppingItemDTO` is.

Comment: I'd probably go for something like reduce/fold instead of forEach. Because you're calculating 2 values and in the absence of a Pair class you'd have to have some sort of object for the 2 values, which could be your Item, but something like CalcResult would probably look nicer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going at it the wrong way.

First of all remember that [`map(mapper)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) requires the mapping function to be:

> a non-interfering, stateless function to apply to each element

In your case, it is **not** non-interfering and stateless because you are modifying the Stream element, which is your `ShoppingItemDTO`. So this is bad.

How can we correct this? Well, we need to think about what we want to achieve here. Your code calculates two values for each `ShoppingItemDTO` and then sums them all together to produce a `ShoppingBasketOutput`.

So, what you want here is to [`reduce`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-U-java.util.function.BiFunction-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) your `itemsDTO` into a `ShoppingBasketOutput`. The identity to use is a new empty `ShoppingBasketOutput`. Everytime we encounter an item, we add to the basket output its subtotal and its discount. The third parameter combines two basket output together by summing their values.

```
public ShoppingBasketOutput getBasketTotalPrice(List<ShoppingItemDTO> itemsDTO) {
    return itemsDTO.stream().reduce(
        new ShoppingBasketOutput(),
        (output, item) -> {
            ItemEnum itemEnum = ItemEnum.getItem(item.getName()).orElseThrow(ProductNotFoundException::new);
            output.setSubTotal(output.getSubTotal() + itemEnum.getPrice() * item.getQuantity());
            output.setTotalDiscount(output.getTotalDiscount() + getItemTotalDiscount(itemEnum, item.getQuantity()));
            return output;
        },
        (output1, output2) -> {
            output1.setSubTotal(output1.getSubTotal() + output2.getSubTotal());
            output1.setTotalDiscount(output1.getTotalDiscount() + output2.getTotalDiscount());
            return output1;
        }
    );
}
```

Notice that you could this code a lot cleaner by introducing two methods `addToSubTotal(amount)` and `addToTotalDiscount(amount)`. With such methods, you would need to get and set the new values.

Answer (score 2):

This is same answer as that of Tunaki, which I have marked as accepted answer, and refactored it little bit by moving the logic into separate methods rather than everything into same method.

```
public ShoppingBasketOutput getBasketTotalPrice(List<ShoppingItemDTO> itemsDTO) {
    return itemsDTO.stream()
            .reduce(
                    new ShoppingBasketOutput(),
                    this::calculateItemPrice,
                    this::calculateBasketPrice
            );
}

private ShoppingBasketOutput calculateBasketPrice(ShoppingBasketOutput firstOutput, ShoppingBasketOutput secondOutput) {
    firstOutput.setSubTotal(firstOutput.getSubTotal() + secondOutput.getSubTotal());
    firstOutput.setTotalDiscount(firstOutput.getTotalDiscount() + secondOutput.getTotalDiscount());
    return firstOutput;
}

private ShoppingBasketOutput calculateItemPrice(ShoppingBasketOutput output, ShoppingItemDTO item) {
    ItemEnum itemEnum = ItemEnum.getItem(item.getName()).orElseThrow(ProductNotFoundException::new);
    output.setSubTotal(output.getSubTotal() + itemEnum.getPrice() * item.getQuantity());
    output.setTotalDiscount(output.getTotalDiscount() + getItemTotalDiscount(itemEnum, item.getQuantity()));
    return output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why is `calculateItemPrice` returning it's argument. It could be `void`.

Try this (not tested)

```
public ShoppingBasketOutput getBasketTotalPrice(List<ShoppingItemDTO> itemsDTO) {
    ShoppingBasketOutput shoppingBasketOutput = new ShoppingBasketOutput();

    itemsDTO.forEach(this::calculateItemPrice);

    shoppingBasketOutput.setSubTotal(
      itemsDTO.stream().mapToDouble(ip -> ip.getSubTotal()).sum()
    );

    shoppingBasketOutput.setTotalDiscount(
      itemsDTO.stream().mapToDouble(ip -> ip.getTotalDiscount()).sum()
    );

    return shoppingBasketOutput;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've got the constructors available and don't want to create any other classes:

```
public ShoppingBasketOutput getBasketTotalPrice(List<ShoppingItemDTO> itemsDTO) {
    ShoppingItemDTO res = itemsDTO.stream().map(this::calculateItemPrice).reduce(new ShoppingItemDTO(0, 0),
            (l, r) -> new ShoppingItemDTO(l.getItemSubTotal() + r.getItemSubTotal(),
                    l.getItemTotalDiscount() + r.getItemTotalDiscount()));

    return new ShoppingBasketOutput(res.getItemSubTotal(), res.getItemTotalDiscount());
}
```